# ASP.NET MVC stack overflow exception when calling a partial view from master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stack-overflow

I'm getting a stack overflow error when I try to call a partial view from the master.

**The Partial View:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<form action="/members/TestLoginProcess/" method="post">
U: <input type="text" name="mUsername" /><br />
P: <input type="password" name="mHash" /><br />
<button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

**The Action in the "Members" controller**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult TestLogin()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Then I call the partial view from the **master page**:

```
<!--Excerpt from wopr.master--> 
<%= Html.Action("TestLogin", "Members")%>
```

When I go into debug mode the master page returns this error:

> {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

I don't understand how this error is getting triggered. any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the call stack in the debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm new to Visual Basic Web Developer so sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: is this what you're asking for? :An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Comment: I did a quick google search on vwd call stack... is this helpfull? :> App_Web_jk8x_wbh.dll!ASP.views_shared_wopr_master.__Render__control1(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter __w = {System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter}, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer = {ASP.views_shared_wopr_master}) Line 13 + 0x25 bytes C#

Comment: What function(s) are repeated many times in the call stack window?

Comment: stack window repeats this line over and over: > App_Web_tkozxo5d.dll!ASP.views_shared_wopr_master.__Render__control1(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter __w = {System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter}, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer = {ASP.views_shared_wopr_master}) Line 13 + 0x25 bytes C#

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have seen this error before. In my case it happened when i returned a call to View() rather than PartialView() for Html.RenderAction or Html.Action in my action methods.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you change

`<%= Html.Action("TestLogin", "Members")%>`

to

`<%= Html.RenderPartial("TestLogin", "Members");%>`?

Please also note there is a ; at the end of the command.  Miss this and you'll get another error.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the wishes. Unfortunately, when I tried RenderPartial I got this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Comment: I took the "=" out and that took care of that error. New errors now :-( I'm gonna troubleshoot this for a while before updating this post.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same thing because I was loading a user control that was essentially a menu bar, but full of Html.Action(), rather than Html.ActionLink(), so it was continuously calling the Action and because it went back to a page that inherited the same masterpage, was calling it again...and again...and again.

So yeah my problem was I was using the wrong keyword.