# ASP.NET MVC 3: StackOverflowException when using PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've tried converting an MVC 2 tutorial webshop to MVC 3 with Razor Syntax, but I don't understand the following problem...

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<div id="header"> 

    <div class="title">SPORTS STORE</div>

</div>

<div id ="categories">
@{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav");}
</div>
```

"Menu" is an action for a partial View on the "Nav" Controller.

**Menu.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebShop_1_0.ViewModels.NavLink>

 @{foreach(var link in Model)
 {
        Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues, new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "class", link.IsSelected ? "selected" : null }
    });
 }}
```

**This is the Nav controller**

```
public class NavController : Controller
{
    private IProductsRepository productsRepository;

    public NavController(IProductsRepository productsRepository)
    {
        this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult Menu(string category)
    {
        // Just so we don't have to write this code twice
        Func<string, NavLink> makeLink = categoryName => new NavLink
        {
            Text = categoryName ?? "Home",
            RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Products",
                action = "List",
                category = categoryName,
                page = 1
            }),
            IsSelected = (categoryName == category)
        };

        // Put a Home link at the top
        List<NavLink> navLinks = new List<NavLink>();
        navLinks.Add(makeLink(null));

        // Add a link for each distinct category
        //navLinks.AddRange(productsRepository.Products.Select(x => x.Category.Trim()).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x));

        var categories = productsRepository.Products.Select(x => x.Category.Trim());
        foreach (string categoryName in categories.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
            navLinks.Add(makeLink(categoryName));

        return View(navLinks);
    }
}
```

I don't know where the mistake is.

If I use Html.PartialView instead of Html.RenderAction, I get another error message, that VS can't find the PartialView. Most of this is code that I have just copied, just the Views rewritten to MVC 3.

Before this StackOverFlowException problem, the browser would load the webpage for a long time.

**This is the routing:**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        /*Sorrend geccire számít*/
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(null, "", // Only matches the empty URL (i.e. ~/)
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Products",
                            action = "List",
                            category = (string)null,
                            page = 1
                        }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null, "Page{page}", // Matches ~/Page2, ~/Page123, but not ~/PageXYZ
                        new { controller = "Products", action = "List", category = (string)null },
                        new { page = @"\d+" } // Constraints: page must be numerical
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}", // Matches ~/Football or ~/AnythingWithNoSlash
                        new { controller = "Products", action = "List", page = 1 }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}/Page{page}", // Matches ~/Football/Page567
                        new { controller = "Products", action = "List" }, // Defaults
                        new { page = @"\d+" } // Constraints: page must be numerical
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactroy());

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cart), new CartModelBlinder());
    }
}
```

Comment: any stack trace? this might really help since StackOverflow might indicate recursion. btw, i am sure you are asking at the right place ;)

Comment: try `return PartialView(navLinks);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC stack overflow exception when calling a partial view from master page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814824/asp-net-mvc-stack-overflow-exception-when-calling-a-partial-view-from-master-pag)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your Menu action needs to return a PartialView(navLinks) instead of View(navLinks), otherwise your layout will be drawn with the menu, which causes recursion. Oh oh! This causes the stack overflow :)

Comment: And must change `public ViewResult Menu(string category)` to `public ActionResult Menu(string category)`

Comment: I had this same problem.  Is this an error in the book, or is this a change with MVC3 over MVC2?

Comment: Probably an error in the book. I believe "View" has always rendered with layouts.